# What is the purpose of fill attribute on svg tag?

Tags: css, svg

As far as I know, SVG `fill` attribute is used to paint the object. And as per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill), `fill` is applicable on following elements:

```
<altGlyph> | <circle> | <ellipse> | <path> | <polygon> | <polyline> | <rect> | <text> | <textPath> | <tref> | <tspan>
```

However, the root `svg` element also accepts the `fill` property. Initially, I thought it is setting the `background-color` for the SVG but that is not the case!

**So what is the use of this property on `svg` tag?**

Comment: It "accepts" the property, sure, but the `<svg>` also accepts the `steve` property ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/53rst6mc/)) without complaint, though it serves no purpose, no role, no function or utility; and the documentation you quote, and link to, doesn't suggest that either `"steve"`, *or* `fill`, are valid attributes for the `<svg>` element.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am working on Figma API that returns `svg` with `fill` property. To sanitize this SVG, I need to understand why Figma API returns `svg` with `fill`. Even I am surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A common use case: Icon Coloring**
All child elements will inherit the parent fill property:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
}

body {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon icon-prefix-home" id="icon-prefix-home" viewBox="0 0 34 48" fill="currentColor">
  <path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-prefix-home" id="icon-prefix-home" viewBox="0 0 34 48" fill="currentColor">
  <path fill="green" d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
</svg>
```

This method can be useful if your svg contains many assets to be reused e.g as `<use>` instances:

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  height:1em;
  vertical-align:-0.1em;
}

a{
  color: red;
  font-size:5em;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgIcons" class="svgIcons" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
      <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
        <path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 27 48">
        <path d="M26.16,17.92l-10.44,10.44l10.44,10.44l-2.44,2.44l-10.44-10.44l-10.44,10.44l-2.44-2.44l10.44-10.44l-10.44-10.44l2.44-2.44l10.44,10.44l10.44-10.44Z" />
      </symbol>
</svg>

<a href="#">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 34 48" fill="currentColor">
    <use href="#close" />
  </svg> currentColor
</a>

<a href="#">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 34 48">
    <use href="#home" />
  </svg> default Color
</a>
```

Comment: Stupid of me. I should have thought about the CSS inheritance. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Harshal Patil: not stupid at all! svg's attribute inheritance model is in many ways similar to css but still different. E.g  styling properties can easily be omitted like `fill` whereas geometry properties like radius are mandatory. Besides, you raise a good point regarding GUI app, API etc. generated output:  Quite likely, there are useless attributes you could/should strip from your svg markup to facilitate your development tasks. Eventually, there are still some rendering related issues (quantom, blink, webkit) – mostly related to a browser's tolerance towards non-compliant markup.